# Pokemon Go Verifying Wrong Email

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I changed my Pokemon Go email, but I think I might have accedently typed the wrong email now it's asking me to verify when I go on the game and it won't let me check the email I typed or let me change it and I can't verify it. Please help me!

Comment: And when I try to check the email on Pokemon Go site, I login and it automatically sends me to the verify page where I CANT VERIFY, just wanted to clear it up

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I just happened to write the email account for my friend's account. If you haven't pressed the "vertify" button on the app but just closed it, you can go in on the webbrowser and sign out of your account on google, then open the app again and sign up with google. Then you can just sign in and it worked for me. So that can definitely be an opportunity if you messed up like I did. :)

Answer (score -2):

I am in the same boat, I've emailed tech support but I don't expect a reply anytime soon with the amount of work they must have at the mo!

You can check if you did enter the wrong email by trying to sign up again - it will tell you if your email address is already associated to an account.

I take it you've checked your junk folders?

As far as I can work out there is no way to change the email address associated with the account without logging in first - which of course you can't do without verifying >.<

Hopefully they will get back to a tech support email aventually because I had made good progress on PokemonGo already, in the meantime I've started again from scratch using a Google account, hopefully can trade over the Pokemon at some point in the future!

Comment: Yeah man me too, I for now have started over and just waiting for a replay on their contacts on social media but no answer yet, I have sent an email too. I did do what you said about the email assosiated with an account and both my emails don't match so I know it's the wrong email